# Excel: Indirect() - Populate summary sheet from other named sheets in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

How do I use INDIRECT() [or another function] in excel to combine a name sheet reference and cell reference?

## Problem Context:

I have an excel spreadsheet which contains a set of named sheets:

```
 [1] "S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839"  "S10000_T4.3.0_201703301843" 
 [3] "S20000_R3.3.2_201703301826"  "S20000_T4.3.0_201703301832" 
 [5] "S30000_R3.3.2_201703301803"  "S30000_T4.3.0_201703301817" 
 [7] "S40000_R3.3.2_201703301738"  "S40000_T4.3.0_201703301752" 
 [9] "S50000_R3.3.2_201703301707"  "S50000_T4.3.0_201703301724" 
[11] "S60000_R3.3.2_201703301624"  "S60000_T4.3.0_201703301647" 
[13] "S70000_R3.3.2_201703301535"  "S70000_T4.3.0_201703301602" 
[15] "S80000_R3.3.2_201703301430"  "S80000_T4.3.0_201703301508" 
[17] "S90000_R3.3.2_201703301324"  "S90000_T4.3.0_201703301400" 
[19] "S260000_R3.3.2_201704021725" "S260000_T4.3.0_201704021929"
[21] "S270000_R3.3.2_201704021241" "S270000_T4.3.0_201704021529"
[23] "S280000_R3.3.2_201704020847" "S280000_T4.3.0_201704021100"
[25] "S290000_R3.3.2_201704020447" "S290000_T4.3.0_201704020702"
[27] "S310000_R3.3.2_201704012331" "S310000_T4.3.0_201704020242"
[29] "S320000_R3.3.2_201704011827" "S320000_T4.3.0_201704012128"
[31] "S330000_R3.3.2_201704011304" "S330000_T4.3.0_201704011546"
[33] "S340000_R3.3.2_201704010652" "S340000_T4.3.0_201704011010"
[35] "S350000_R3.3.2_201704010020" "S350000_T4.3.0_201704010404"
[37] "S360000_R3.3.2_201703311819" "S360000_T4.3.0_201703312134"
[39] "S370000_R3.3.2_201703310914" "S370000_T4.3.0_201703311301"
[41] "S380000_R3.3.2_201703310134" "S380000_T4.3.0_201703310509"
[43] "S390000_R3.3.2_201703301846" "S390000_T4.3.0_201703302252"
```

Each sheet contains a set of timing data...

```
function.   user    system  elapsed
DT read input   2.144   0.63    12.274
DT Convert Date to Date Format  0.263   0.065   1.104
DT select via scan  0.024   0.001   0.047
```

I also have a sheet named hidden that has a list of the sheet names.

## Objective

I want to be able to populate a summary sheet from each of the sheets using cell references. ***I would love to be able to enter one formula on the summary spreadsheet and drag right so that the sheet references increment...***

### Example:

I want to be able to combine the sheet name with a cell reference that returns the value on the referenced sheet.

For example:

`=S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839!A1` will return 'function' based on the above example data. i.e. Return value referenced at cell A1 on sheet `S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839`

now I could use the hidden sheet to return the sheet names...

`=Hidden!A1`  will return `S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839`

## Problem:

***I cannot seem to combine the sheet reference with a cell reference where the cell reference will increment when I pull down or right.*** I appear to be creating a single string not a combination of sheet name and cell reference.

`=INDIRECT("'[Analysis.xlsx]hidden'!A1")` will return `S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839`

I want to now combine that value return with a cell reference...

**S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839**!A1

## Question:

How do I formulate the formula?

Should I use nested **INDIRECT**(hidden'!A1**INDIRECT** or something else?

the hard part appears to be how to allow the cell reference to increment as it is a combination of string concatenation and a cell reference.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/343087-relative-cell-reference-within-indirect-formula.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INDIRECT` gets the sheet name but not also the cell on that sheet, so you need to add that bit on the end:

```
=INDIRECT('[Analysis.xlsx]hidden'!A1 & "!A1")
```

If you want to be able to drag down and/or accross, experiment with the `ADDRESS` function. Something like this:

```
=INDIRECT('[Analysis.xlsx]hidden'!A1 & "!" & ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1)))
```

Comment: Sir, thank you - How do make the second !A1 increment, the first A1 is the fixed. I want to resolve too `S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839!A1` and have the A1 increment as I drag right or down. I hope that clarifies. Thank you for your time and help - it is very much appreciated. In the example given the second !A1 appears fixed.

Comment: @Technophobe01, I've updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Sir, thank you! Perfect - your help is very much appreciated. Good karma flying your way.